# ! LaTeX Error: \begin{pspicture} on input line 11 ended by \end{cards}

Tags: pdftex

I got pdf option sent to pstricks, and then used pdflatex --shell-escape to compile Olaf's poker.sty modified file. I replaced the .eps graphics with .svg \includesvg graphics.

Now it's giving me weird errors. Here is the tail of the poker-ranks.log file:

```
> > \@envbody=\toks34 ))) Package caption Info: Begin \AtBeginDocument code. Package caption Info: subfig package v1.3 is loaded. Package
> caption Info: End \AtBeginDocument code.
> 
> <poker-ranks-pics.pdf, id=2, page=1, 40.15pt x 55.20625pt> File:
> poker-ranks-pics.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
> 
> <use poker-ranks-pics.pdf, page 1> Package pdftex.def Info:
> poker-ranks-pics.pdf, page1 used on input line 11. (pdftex.def)       
> Requested size: 40.14989pt x 55.2061pt.
> 
> 
> ! LaTeX Error: \begin{pspicture} on input line 11 ended by
> \end{cards}.
> 
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H
> <return>  for immediate help.  ...                                    
> 
>                                                    l.20 \end{cards}
>                  ? X   Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:  13523 strings out of 493104  232925 string characters out of 6136932 
> 351179 words of memory out of 5000000  16717 multiletter control
> sequences out of 15000+600000  4218 words of font info for 15 fonts,
> out of 8000000 for 9000  1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191 
> 75i,8n,100p,665b,569s stack positions out of
> 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s No pages of output. PDF statistics: 
> 2 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)  0 named destinations out of
> 1000 (max. 500000)  11 words of extra memory for PDF output out of
> 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

It did make convert the svg to a pdf but then it broke.

It fails with what looks like a mismatched \begin \end.  Any ideas about this kind of error? Thanks

OK I took my \includesvg commands out of poker.sty and ran raw latex against poker-ranks.tex and it spat out a bunch of errors that I hit enter through so David C. you are right, this might predate my changes to it.  But when I did that, it did make a .dvi and that converted makes the proper .pdf.

[output poker ranks .pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ek8j4ii96rte8k/poker-ranks.pdf?dl=0)
[poker-ranks.tex](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t42tsu2bgddimzj/poker-ranks.tex?dl=0)
[poker.sty](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uvs4gktd216l2w5/poker.sty?dl=0)
[poker-ranks.log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c9q7bk68x9hcdgc/poker-ranks.log?dl=0)
[poker0.81.tar.gz](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wynf9e9bx89w7ze/poker4latex.081.tar.gz?dl=0)

Comment: Sometimes MWE may be unneeded, but in this case it is rather necessary.

Comment: The most likely cause of that error is an input of the form `\begin{pspicture}\end{cards}` That's what latex says the input is, if it is not that you need to show us what it is.

Comment: OK what is MWE?

Comment: min­i­mal work­ing ex­am­ple (MWE). Actually, your comment was unhelpful since it presupposed knowledge that wasn't necessarily obvious.  You can get the errors by running against poker latex package on poker-ranks.tex.